# How to get BouncingScrollPhysics overscroll value offset?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

For example, I have `SingleChildScrollView` with `BouncingScrollPhysics`.
I want something like `print(_overscrollOffsetValue)` when content jumps from edge, e.g. the more offset value of overscroll, the bigger `_overscrollOffsetValue`.

Comment: you can use `NotificationListener` for that (with `ScrollNotification` / `OverscrollNotification`)

Comment: update, sorry: `OverscrollNotification` does not seem to work... ;-(

Comment: @pskink Exactly! That's why I opened this question.

Comment: ok `OverscrollNotification` works with `ClampingScrollPhysics` so you need to check how it is implemented (most likely in `ClampingScrollSimulation` - but i am not 100% sure), btw there is also `OverscrollIndicatorNotification`.. but nobody knows how to get it ;-(

Comment: anyway i found it: when `ScrollPhysics.applyBoundaryConditions` returns != 0 it means the overscroll  and then `OverscrollNotification` is dispatched

Comment: @pskink So how can it be used ?

Comment: @pskink Oh, I see - you're saying it's impossible?

Comment: impossible? no, you need a custom `ScrollPhysics` ;-)

Comment: @pskink I had this idea, but didn't find any good documentation or materials on how to do this in my case :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can listen for ScrollUpdateNotification:

```
NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
  onNotification: (notification) {
    if (notification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
      final offset = notification.metrics.pixels;
      if (offset < 0) {
        print(offset.abs());
      }
    }
    return false;
  },
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
    child: Text('A' * 10000),
  ),
)
```

Comment: The idea is taken from [flutter_stretchy_header](https://github.com/diegoveloper/flutter_stretchy_header) package